# Signing a XFA-based PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, xfa

I have a XFA-based PDF with some fields need to be signed. However, these fields are embedded in the XFA form, so I can't sign it using the following codes

```
public void sign(String keystore, char[] password, String src, String name, String dest)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystore), password);
    String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, password);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);

    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(name);
    // Creating the signature
    PrivateKeySignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, "BC");
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
}
```

For example, I have a field named "root[0].mainpage[0].root[2].DefaultPage[0].Page1[0].SignArea[0].GSA[0].GSF-shinfo_sh-tmp03_sh_sf[0]". When I tried to put it to the argument "name", I got the error message

*"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field root[0].mainpage[0].root[2].DefaultPage[0].Page1[0].SignArea[0].GSA[0].GSF-shinfo_sh-tmp03_sh_sf[0] does not exist."*

I've worked on this problem for a week, but I haven't come up with a solution. Is there any ideas about this issue? Thanks!

PS:This is the [download url](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tj2uhmg7nb5p65h/XFASign.pdf?dl=0) of the file.

Comment: `MakeSignature.signDetached` creates a PDF signature in an AcroForm form field. For creating signatures in XFA form fields, you might want to try the `MakeXmlSignature` class instead.

Comment: I've tried `MakeXmlSignature` class. However, I can't set the name of the signature field since there is no method to do this. What's worse, after I signed the file using `MakeXmlSignature`, I will get a "verify operation failed" warning when I tried to open that file. Could you give some advice? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I've attached the original file. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: This is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mr9l3ww3eg5fa65/Signed_1.pdf?dl=0) of the "verify operation failed" file.

Comment: I'll look at that later.

Comment: First of all, the original file already contained a signature, a usage rights signature, and your signing has not been done as an incremental update; thus, that ur signature broke. Have you made sure that you created the stamper in append mode in your code using `MakeXmlSignature`, too? Furthermore, can you please supply the file in unsigned form, too?